# Spring - Why do we need mark a class @repository(or whatever other than @Component)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to learn `Spring in Detail` so in my sample I having a `DAO`

```
@Repository
public class EmployeeDAOImpl implements EmployeeDAO {
    ...
}
```

it is working fine, but the same with `@Component` too working fine without any issue

```
@Component
public class EmployeeDAOImpl implements EmployeeDAO {
    ...
}
```

So why do I want to mark my
class with `@Repository`, and advantages there other than stereotype for persistence layer?

Comment: I would never agree with downvoter, there is something more we get  when we annotate a class with `@Repository`, let me find the answer

Comment: A class annotated with @Repository is eligible for Spring `DataAccessException` translation when used in conjunction with a `org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor` `PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the source code of `Repository` that is also a `Component`

```
@Component
public @interface Repository { ... }
```

It's just there to make clear the purpose of the component/bean.

In the same way `Service` and `Controller` are also a `Component` that is used for services and controllers.